# Is there a currently known JS bug preventing voting and other actions?

Tags: bug, voting, javascript

Starting this morning, I've been unable to vote or view more comments, or do most other actions.  I've seen the same issue in multiple SE sites (Philosophy, Musicfans) and multiple browsers (FF, Chrome).

I am accessing SE from behind a work firewall, but I've never seen this issue before.  The JS console indicates an issue finding the Stack Exchange JS object.

Is this a known, universal issue, or specific to me?

NOTE: I do not seem to be experiencing the same issues here in META.

Comment: Something on your end is blocking the CDN of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Same here! I was going to write up a question here as soon as I got a chance. SO and Meta.SE are the only sites that seem to work fully. Sometimes I have problems loading posts to review on SO, too (and I can't load reviews on any other site). It started for me this morning, too.

Comment: This is definitely related to my work network and undoubtedly yours. On my work laptop and personal computer I have no issues when browsing SE sites while connected to my personal wireless network, but when I VPN into my work network via my personal wireless network I can't vote, comment, etc.

Comment: It seems fixed as of today.  I still don't know if it was caused by something that changed here at my workplace or by something that changed at SE.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Seems fixed for me, too. I don't think it was your workplace because I'm pretty sure we don't work at the same company (and our locations are quite different).

Comment: @Null - Maybe SE made a change that doesn't play nice with firewalls?  And they reversed it?